# Will Ubuntu run slower in a virtual machine?

Tags: dual-boot, vmware

I have been using Ubuntu 10.04 for some time now as a dual boot system but on separate stand alone partition on the same machine. However I have decided to use it from the same partition but through windows using VMware v8, so is there any possibility to be able to boot it from with in windows while Ubuntu being on a separate dual boot partition, already installed? And how much speed impact there would be on Ubuntu 10.04 64bit LTS if the VMware v8 software being used is 32bit itself on a 32bit windows XP pro also?

If the above scenario is not possible to boot Ubuntu from with in windows using VMware v8 then is there any alternative available to do boot Ubuntu in the said way?

Comment: can have a look over here http://www.vmware.com/pdf/dualboot_tech_note.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You most definitely can.  I have Ubuntu on my machine,(Dual core 3.2, 4GB RAM, 250HD and 2 80GB Drives) Unfortunately Windows as well.

I also have VMware 8 installed, and I have Ubuntu 12.04, 10.04LTS, and 12.10 all running inside VM's.  Once you have VMware installed, you can virutally boot any operating system of your choice, providing you have the hardware to handle it.

Running One OS, doesn't really require much, but some OS's require a lot of hardware ie. Windows.  Ubuntu runs great, but of course, if I run all 3 VM's at the same time, it gets a bit sluggish.  Hope that this answers your question.